# What is the intent that the stock Samsung Galaxy S2 gallery app fires when "Send" is clicked?

Tags: android, android-intent

I currently have the following problem:

I want to receive images with my app that are sent from other apps. So I have registered the following intent-filters:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

It worked fine for my gallery app (CM9) and a bunch of third party gallery apps i have installed via Play Store (Quick Pic etc...).

But then the client complained that his gallery app (stock Galaxy S2) doesn't show my app in the list when clicks the "Send" button. Interesting side-note: There is also a "Send via" button, which shows up the apps normally (and thus seems to be the SEND_MULTIPLE intent).

The "Send" button shows the following apps:

- Bluetooth
- Email
- Google Mail
- Messaging
- Wi-Fi Direcct

That's it.

So my question is: Which Intent could this possible be that I have to register for? Can't find any intent for sending files/multiple files other then SEND and SEND_MUTLIPLE :(

Any ideas?

Comment: What makes you think that this is a normal chooser? Plenty of apps skip the chooser and hard-wire in their own list of apps in a list dialog. Besides, if the third entry really is "Google Mail", then it can't be a chooser, because Gmail is always referred to as Gmail by the app itself.

Comment: this may be correct for the english version of the gmail app, in Germany it is always named "Google Mail" because of some legal issues. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake. Still, though, it may not be a standard chooser, but rather a custom dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the Galaxy S2 the ShareIntent appears if the user press menu. That 'Share to' menu on the screen is hard coded by Samsung and you can't override it.